# Cannot access table contents in siebel open ui

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, siebel

I am trying to implement a particular code in Siebel Open UI which access the attribute value of a particular column from a table. The same code when I run in the console I am getting the desired value. But when implemented inside the PR file I am getting the attribute value as undefined. The following is my code:

```
  TilesPR.prototype.ShowUI = function()

    {
       console.log("Inside show ui");
       SiebelAppFacade.TilesPR.superclass.ShowUI.call( this );
       var pm = this.GetPM();
       var placeholder= pm.Get( "GetFullId" );
       console.log('The fullId is '+placeholder);
       var table_id=placeholder.split('A')
       console.log('The table_id is '+table_id[1]);
       var table_string='s_'+table_id[1]+'_l';
       console.log("The table_string value is "+table_string);
         $('#'+table_string).css('border','2px solid black');//This code works
        var i=0;
        $('#'+table_string+' tbody tr').each(function()
        {
        console.log("Inside the function");
        i++;
        var x=i+'Account_Status';
        console.log(x);
        $('#'+x).attr('name');
        var valuee= $('#'+x).attr('name');
        console.log(valuee);//Gives me undefined all the time

        });

    };
```

Can somebody please help me with the situation?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hey Geethu Ann Joseph,

I assume you have here a List Applet with a lot of values.

You should always try to work with Siebel Open UI Commands, espacially in this case because you want to get the values from the Front-End (this can be a bad side effect in some cases) so try to get the information right out of the Business Component, with the Siebel Open UI Commands.

So lets assume you want all informations out of an List Applet you should get the ResultSet and then read the values out of it.

```
var resultSet = this.GetPM().Get("ResultSet");
```

it will return you a JavaScript Object with all results in the List so you can read the value that you want to use.

Then you have to read it with,...

```
var resultSet = this.GetPM().Get("ResultSet");
resultSet[<<RowID>>][<<Control Name>>]
Example: resultSet[0]["Status"]
```

I hope that helped you and good luck in the next steps of Open UI.

Kind regards,
Myracle